# JSONModel changing only one element

Tags: sapui5

Is it possible to change only one element in a JSONModel and have the binded control to only reload that one specific element?

Example:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John Smith",
    "address": "1111 fake street"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jane Smith",
    "address": "2222 fake street"
  }
]
```

Suppose i want to change the address of Jane Smith, I would use `JSONModel.SetData()` to set the update object into the JSONModel. After doing this the whole binded control will reload itself. This is fine for such a small object, but if i have a object that has 100 elements and I am loading it on a phone it is very slow.

So how can I reload only specific portions of the control without reloading the whole control?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSONModel provides a method **setProperty** which can be used to set the value of a specific property. After the value has been set the JSONModel will check its bindings automatically for changes. You cannot avoid that.

In your case it would look like:

```
model.setProperty("/1/address", "13th Elm Street");
```

I'm not sure if this example shows how you store your data in the model. In genereal it is advisable to use a named property to allow declaritive data binding in XML views. An example would be:

```
{ "persons" : [ {
    "name": "John Smith",
    "address": "1111 fake street"
  }, 
  {
    "name": "Jane Smith",
    "address": "2222 fake street"
  } ]
}
```

Then you would set the address like:

```
model.setProperty("/persons/1/address", "13th Elm Street");
```